# How to rescale x-axis of time series (C3js)?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

In C3.js there's a way to rescale the y-axis when you zoom in. Does a similar function exist for the x-axis?

Similar code from the chart

```
var visualizeThis = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#this',
    data: {
      x: 'Dates',
      columns:[
          dates,
          dataPoints
      ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%m/%d/%Y'
            }
        }
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        rescale: true //this only rescales the y-axis
    },
    point: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In c3.js the zoom affects to x-axis as shown by this [example](http://c3js.org/samples/interaction_zoom.html).

If you want to scale y-axis also, you can try `zoom.rescale` option.

```
zoom: {
  enabled: true,
  rescale: true
}
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcrqpbro/).

Comment: When I mean by rescale, I want the other dates for my time series to populate the x-axis when I zoom in. I'm aware of the feature you pointed out.